# Is there a typo in this runtime analysis of selection sort?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, sorting

This is from https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/02-25/19-sorting2-select-insert-shell.pdf, slide 6.

The instructor is doing a runtime analysis of selection sort. Here is what he has

[image]

From step 1 to step 2, is there a typo?

From what I worked out

(N-1 - (i + 1) + 1)
Should evaluate to 
(N-1 - i - 1 + 1)
which evaluates to (N - i - 1) not (N-1 + 1). 
Or am i missing some step in the summation

Comment: $N-(i+1) = N-i-1$, so yes, a typo removal of the brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The last line should read
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (N - i -1).
$$

The next line of the slide also has an error: rather than
$$
N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1  - \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} i,
$$
it should read
$$
N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1  - \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (i + 1) \qquad \text{or} \qquad
N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1  - \sum_{i=1}^{N} i
$$
and the concluding equality should be
$$
N^2 - \frac{N(N+1)}{2},
$$
or simply
$$
\frac{N(N-1)}{2}.
$$

Probably the author is being rather sloppy since they only care about the asymptotic size (the big-O time) so in the end, none of this matters.

Comment: Thank you i didn't think would matter anyways